# ruby class to java class using jruby

Tags: java, ruby, eclipse, jruby

i found the following ruby app in git:
https://github.com/chrislo/sourceclassifier
and it is exactly what i need for the final part of my school project.
It would be great if i could use it in a my java project.

i used jRuby and managed to compile the class i need ( sourceclassifier.rb ) to a Java .class file, and added it to the build path of my eclipse app.

how can i now use it inside my app?
using `sourceclassifier s = new sourceclassifier()` throws me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sourceclassifier/lib/sourceclassifier
    at StackOverFlowReader.main(StackOverFlowReader.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sourceclassifier.lib.sourceclassifier
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more`
```

and help will be appreciated,
Boris.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include your java code, or perhaps write a little java app that highlights the problem.

Comment: there's nothing much to add - sourceclassifier  is the Ruby class i compiled to java given in the first link i posted. and all i do is i try to instance that class. i just don't realy know how jRuby works to know where the problem is.
If i may, one more question - after i compile a simple class A with lets say 1 method f, i'm suppose to be able to do A a = new A(); a.f(); in my java app?

Comment: Did you modify the github source at all?  Do you realise that gem depends on other gems (namely, classify)?  Did you use jruby-complete.jar?  Please detail the exact steps you've taken - you'll have a better chance of getting an answer....